# Command name printed before execution

Tags: 20.04, windows-10

I am new to ubuntu and bash.

Whenever I execute a command in ubuntu it prints itself before executing. For example, what I get after running `echo "Hello"` in Windows bash:

```
Hello
```

what I get in ubuntu

```
echo "Hello"
Hello
```

How to solve it?

Edit: Output after running `echo $-` on my ubuntu:

```
himBHs
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `echo $-` so we can see your shell options (in particular whether the shell's `-v` option is set)

Answer (score 0):

After reloading my computer and ubuntu, the problem strangely got fixed.